# Whilst I have been recovering from surgery--how can I tell it is an attributive clause or an adverbial clause in this case?

Tags: grammar

Everyone. The following is part of Kate’s cancer diagnosis announcement; and I have two questions:

> I wanted to take this opportunity to say thank you, personally, for all the wonderful messages of support and for your understanding whilst I have been recovering from surgery.

1. Is the "whilst I have been recovering from surgery" an attributive clause for the "for all the wonderful messages of support and for your understanding" or just for the "for your understanding"?
2. Could it be that "whilst I have been recovering from surgery" be an adverbial clause for "I wanted to take this opportunity to say thank you ..."?

Comment: BBC's Chinese translation treat the "whilst" clause as an attributive just to the antecedent "your understanding". So, I got the questions.

Comment: English is a "living" language. Anglophones living today [almost never use ***whilst*** in your cited context.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Whilst+I+have+been%2CWhile+I+have+been&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=10)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is inherently ambiguous, but pragmatics strongly suggests that the 'whilst I have been recovering from surgery' refers to either the nearest NP (in the coordination) 'your understanding' or to both 'all the wonderful messages of support' ***and*** 'your understanding'.  (Here, the temporal string is too far from 'I wanted to take this opportunity' for reference to that clause to be the default sense, and Gricean maxims thus strongly advise that the sentence should be re-ordered if the other sense is intended:

- I want[ed] to take the opportunity, while I am recovering from surgery, to say thank you personally for all the wonderful messages of support and for your understanding.                 )

I'd also say the alternative meaning seems less likely.

It hardly makes a difference in this example *which* of the two remaining meanings is taken; I'd say the default is usually for the nearest complete NP ('your understanding' here) to be the one addressed.

Using 'wanted' in place of synonymous (here) 'want' (where the thank you mentioned is the actual sentence here rather than say two weeks ago) is a hedging device, sounding friendlier, more sincere.

Comment: I do appreciate your reply.

Answer (score 1):

Interpretation #2 leads to a contradiction. It would imply that she has been thanking people all along while she has been recovering. But "take this opportunity" means that she's first doing something now, she hasn't been doing it throughout her recovery.

So this meaning is unlikely.

Either of the two possibilities in #1 is possible. But there's no reason to think that only one of them occurred during her recovery (why would people send messages of support in any other time?), it almost certainly applies to both.